# PHP script terminates while require_once() is called on class

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let me preface this by saying I have never worked with php before.

I have inherited a legacy php and I am trying to dockerize it since no one knows how to set up the server environment its currently running under.  This app is using code igniter and I can't get it to load the log-in page.  When I debug the app its stopping execution while calling require_once() on a class.  I have noticed while debugging that when a class is required the debugger will step through the class declaration line, the open curly brace and then skip to the closing curly brace of the class declaration.  However on this class that won't load, it steps on the class declaration line, the open curly brace and then disconnects the debugger and returns a blank page in the browser.

**Properly Loaded Class**

```
class Foo //Debugger breaks here
{//Debugger breaks  here
   //Debugger skips all inside code
}//Debugger breaks here
```

**Broken Class**

```
class Logger //Debugger breaks here
{//Debugger breaks here
    //Debugger detaches here and blank page is return on browser
}
```

I have made sure I have the same php extensions installed on my docker container as are installed on the working server because I have seen examples online of how CI will return a blank page if mysql is not installed.  I'm just wondering how I collect more information to figure out what is going on here. When this script stops working there is nothing logged, it just stops.  The same code is working on another server so I must have a configuration problem.

If the database server cannot be reached could it possibly exhibit this behavior?  I'm mind blown that it doesn't throw any exceptions or give me any clue as to what is going wrong.

**EDIT**

I discovered some code that was shutting off display errors and now I have the error.[image]

Still confused as to how this works in the other server environment and not on my docker environment.  I must has something miss configured somewhere...

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? Have you checked your server error logs? Are you running this on localhost or a production server? What version of CI do you have?

Comment: Since it's a legacy php code - any change you are using a new php version which have new reserved words?

Comment: @Alex I do have error reporting enable and its not logging any errors.  I can confirm that its logging debug logs but nothing to do with this error.  I'm running the php server in a docker container but the previous team has it working on a qa server.  There were all logging into that server and doing development through ssh though which is why I'm trying to dockerize the app.

Comment: @Dekel Its running php 5.3.22 and I'm running 5.3.29 in my docker container.

Comment: Please answer all my questions.

Comment: Assuming that class `Logger` is in `Logger.php` try just running `php Logger.php`. If that doesn't help, maybe try adding `if (class_exists('Logger')) return;` as first line.

Comment: the debugger skips this lines of code because you dont jump in as long as you dont instantiate an object of this class - so this is a normal behavior i guess..

Comment: @Alex The CI version is 2.0.2

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels I did notice that if I added class_exists('Logger') to the top of the Logger class it returned true but my breakpoint at the top of the Logger class was never hit before the time it blew up.  Could this mean there is already a class named Logger which is causing the issue?

Comment: @Alex display errors and error reporting were turned off further down in the index.php file which I didn't see.  I have updated my post with the error.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to load a class twice. Remove one instance and things should be ok.